How to fetch messages from a spesific folder, and move to another using Microsoft Graph SDK for PHP
I am trying to read messages from a mailbox by means of Microsoft Graph SDK for PHP.
I want to read from a specific folder - set the 'isRead' to true - and move the email to another folder.
I suppose there is some magic that could be applied to the $requestConfig
$httpClient = GraphClientFactory::createWithConfig($guzzleConfig);
$requestAdapter = new GraphRequestAdapter($authProvider, $httpClient);
$graphServiceClient = GraphServiceClient::createWithRequestAdapter($requestAdapter);


$requestConfig = new MessagesRequestBuilderGetRequestConfiguration(
    queryParameters: MessagesRequestBuilderGetRequestConfiguration::createQueryParameters(
        select: ['subject', 'body', 'from', 'isRead'],
        top: 2
    ),
    headers: ['Prefer' => 'outlook.body-content-type=text']
);


$messages = $graphServiceClient->users()->byUserId($userPrincipalName)->messages()->get($requestConfig)->wait();

$targer_folder = 'Portico_Leverandor-meldinger';

$folders = $this->graphServiceClient->users()->byUserId($userPrincipalName)->mailFolders()->get()->wait();

foreach ($folders->getValue() as $folder)
{
    if ($folder->getDisplayName() == $targer_folder )
    {
        $targer_folder_id = $folder->getId();
        break;
    }

    $childFolders = $this-> graphServiceClient->users()->byUserId($userPrincipalName)->mailFolders()->byMailFolderId($folder->getId())->childFolders()->get()->wait();
    foreach ($childFolders->getValue() as $childFolder)
    {
        if ($childFolder->getDisplayName() == $targer_folder)
        {
            $targer_folder_id = $childFolder->getId();
            break 2;
        }
    }
}

foreach ($messages->getValue() as $message)
{

    // Mark message as read
    $requestBody = new Message();
    $requestBody->setIsRead(true);

    $message_id =  $message->getId();
    $result = $this->graphServiceClient->users()->byUserId($userPrincipalName)->messages()->byMessageId($message_id)->patch($requestBody)->wait();

    // move message to another folder
    $requestBody = new MovePostRequestBody();
    $requestBody->setDestinationId($targer_folder_id);

    $result = $this->graphServiceClient->users()->byUserId($userPrincipalName)->messages()->byMessageId($message_id)->move()->post($requestBody)->wait();

}


Regards

You can start with documentation how to update the message and how to move a message to the new folder

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Perfect, I am now able to set "isRead" and to move message to a new folder.
The last thing I need - is how to list messages from one folder only.

the final piece of the puzzle: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/mailfolder-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=php
